# Bison reduce/reduce conflict if else condition

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I was expecting shift/reduce conlict for if else, but It gave reduce/reduce conflict on line "| IF '(' boolean_statement ')' block".

Here's some information which might help explain the following code:

- `BOOL` is token for keyword used at start of each line to indicate line is boolean operation
- `BOOLEAN` is either "true" or "false" value
- I am using this compiler to convert a language to C code, the language can contain statements like `a,b,c=d+2` which is equivalent to `a=b=c=d+2` in C; and `bool e = f * .N. g + h`, which is equivalent to `e = f && !g || h`.

  ```
  statements:
          statements statement
          | statement
          ;

  statement:
          if_statement
          | BOOL variable_list '=' boolean_statement
          | variable_list '=' integer_statement
          ;

  if_statement:
          IF '(' boolean_statement ')' block ELSE block
          | IF '(' boolean_statement ')' block
          ;

  variable_list:
          variable_list ',' variable
          | variable
          ;

  variable:
          STRING 
          | STRING '[' INTEGER ']'
          | STRING '[' STRING ']'
          ;

  boolean_statement:
          '(' boolean_statement ')'
          | bval '*' boolean_statement
          | bval '+' boolean_statement
          | bval EQ boolean_statement
          | bval NEQ boolean_statement
          | NOT boolean_statement
          | bval
          ;

  bval:
          BOOLEAN   
          | variable
          ;

  integer_statement:
          '(' integer_statement ')'
          | value '+' integer_statement
          | value '*' integer_statement
          | value
          ;

  value:
          INTEGER        
          | variable
          ;

  block:
          statement
          | '{' statements '}'
          ;
  ```

Here is the full code

```
   %{

    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    //stuff from flex that bison needs to know about:
    extern "C" int yylex();
    extern "C" int yyparse();
    extern "C" FILE *yyin;
    extern int line_num;

    void yyerror(const char *s);

    %}

    //C union holding each of the types of tokens that Flex could return
    %union { 
            int ival;
            bool bval;
            char const *sval;
    }

    //symbol defination
    %token <sval> STRING;
    %token <sval> NOT
    %token CONSTANT_SECTION
    %token BOOLEAN_SECTION
    %token INTEGER_SECTION
    %token LOGIC_SECTION
    %token TIMER_SECTION
    %token <sval> BOOLEAN
    %token <ival> INTEGER
    %token <ival> HEX 
    %token ENDL 
    %token BOOL
    %token IF
    %token ELSE
    %token EQ NEQ
    %token AND
    %token OR
    %token SUBROUTINE_END
    %token SUBROUTINE_START
    %token DELAY SECONDS HOURS MINUTES MSEC
    %token GOTO
    %token LABEL
    %token CALL
    //end of declaration section
    %%

    logic:
            costants_declarations boolean_declarations integer_declarations timer_declarations logic_statements
            | boolean_declarations integer_declarations timer_declarations logic_statements
            | logic_statements
            ;

    costants_declarations:
            CONSTANT_SECTION constants  
            ;

    constants:
            constants STRING '=' INTEGER    { cout << "const int " << $2 << " = "  << $4 << ";" << endl; }
            | constants STRING '=' HEX      { cout << "const int " << $2 << " = "  << $4 << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING '=' INTEGER            { cout << "const int " << $1 << " = "  << $3 << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING '=' HEX                { cout << "const int " << $1 << " = "  << $3 << ";" << endl; }
            ;

    boolean_declarations:
            BOOLEAN_SECTION booleans       
            ;

    booleans:
            booleans ',' boolean             
            | booleans boolean               
            | boolean                       
            ;        

    boolean:
            STRING '[' INTEGER ']'          { cout << "bool " << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]" << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING '[' STRING ']'         { cout << "bool " << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]" << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING                        { cout << "bool " << $1 << " = true;" << endl; }
            ;

    integer_declarations:
            INTEGER_SECTION integers
            ;

    integers:
            integers ',' integer            
            | integers integer              
            | integer                      
            ;

    integer:
            STRING '[' INTEGER ']'          { cout << "int " << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]" << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING '[' STRING ']'         { cout << "int " << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]" << ";" << endl; }
            | STRING                        { cout << "int " << $1 << " = 0;" << endl; }
            ;

    timer_declarations:
            TIMER_SECTION timers
            ;

    timers:
            timers ',' timer
            | timers timer
            | timer
            ;

    timer:
            STRING                          { cout << "int " << $1 << ";" << endl; }
            ;

    logic_statements:
            LOGIC_SECTION subroutines statements
            ;

    subroutines:
            /* empty */
            | SUBROUTINE_START STRING statements SUBROUTINE_END STRING
            ;

    statements:
            statements statement
            | statement
            ;

    statement:
            if_statement
            | delay_statement
            | GOTO STRING
            | LABEL
            | CALL STRING
            | BOOL variable_list '=' { cout << " = "; } boolean_statement { cout << ";\n"; } 
            | variable_list '=' { cout << " = "; } integer_statement { cout << ";\n"; }
            ;

    if_statement:
            IF '(' { cout << "if("; } boolean_statement ')' { cout << ")" << endl; } block
            | IF '(' { cout << "if("; } boolean_statement ')' { cout << ")" << endl; } block ELSE block
            ;

    delay_statement:
            DELAY '=' INTEGER SECONDS statement 
            ;

    variable_list:
            variable_list ',' { cout << " = "; } variable
            | variable
            ;

    variable:
            STRING                          { cout << $1; }
            | STRING '[' INTEGER ']'        { cout << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]"; }
            | STRING '[' STRING ']'         { cout << $1 << "[" << $3 << "]"; }
            ;

    boolean_statement:
            '('{ cout << "("; } boolean_statement ')'{ cout << ")"; }
            | bval '+' { cout << " || "; } boolean_statement
            | bval OR { cout << " || "; } boolean_statement
            | bval '*' { cout << " && "; } boolean_statement
            | bval AND { cout << " && "; } boolean_statement
            | bval EQ { cout << " == "; } boolean_statement
            | bval NEQ { cout << " != "; } boolean_statement
            | NOT { cout << $1; } boolean_statement
            | bval
            ;

    bval:
            BOOLEAN                          { cout << $1; }
            | variable
            ;

    integer_statement:
            '('{ cout << "("; } integer_statement ')'{ cout << ")"; }
            | value '+'{ cout << " + "; } integer_statement
            | value '*'{ cout << " * "; } integer_statement
            | value
            ;

    value:
            INTEGER                       { cout << $1; }
            | variable
            ;

    block:
            { cout << "{" << endl; } statement { cout << "}" << endl; }
            | '{' { cout << "{" << endl; } statements '}' { cout << "}" << endl; }
            ;

    //end of grammer section
    %%

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

            // default input is stdin
            // if file is given read from it
            if(argc == 2)
            {
                    // open a file handle to a particular file:
                    FILE *myfile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
                    // make sure it's valid:
                    if (!myfile) {
                            cout << "Can't open "<< argv[1] <<" file" << endl;
                            cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
                            return -1;
                    }
                    // set lex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
                    yyin = myfile;
            }
            else if(argc != 1)
            {
                    cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
                    cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << endl;
                    return -1;
            }

            // parse through the input until there is no more:
            do 
            {
                    yyparse();
            } while (!feof(yyin));
    }

    void yyerror(const char *s) {
        cout << "Parse error on line " << line_num << "!  Message: " << s << endl;
        // might as well halt now:
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: If you switch the order of your if definitions (do the ELSE one second), do you then get the shift/reduce error?

Comment: @MichaelWelch I still get the error, but reduce/reduce no matter the sequence of those two statements.

Comment: @Ruturaj: Please show your entire bison input, including `%` definitions, and make sure you are copying the precise file. The one you present throws a bison syntax error because of the unquoted `+` and `*` in the `boolean_statement` rules. Once I fixed that, bison gave me only the expected shift/reduce conflict, so I conclude that the file you are actually using is different.

Comment: @rici I have added my whole code at end of previous question. Sorry about the quotes, the language uses two types of and or symbols, either */+ or &&/||. That's why I removed some junk and forgot to add quotes.

Comment: @Ruturaj: Thanks, that made it a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the `IF` statement exactly. It's with the mid-rule actions (MRAs) in the two productions for `if_statement`:

```
if_statement:
          IF '(' { cout << "if("; } boolean_statement ')' { cout << ")" << endl; } block
        | IF '(' { cout << "if("; } boolean_statement ')' { cout << ")" << endl; } block ELSE block
        ;
```

A mid-rule action, like `{ cout << "if("; }`, is translated to a uniquely-named empty non-terminal. In effect, the above productions are turned into the following:

```
if_statement:
          IF '(' @3 boolean_statement ')' @4 block
        | IF '(' @5 boolean_statement ')' @6 block ELSE block
        ;

@3: %empty { cout << "if("; }        ;
@4: %empty { cout << ")" << endl; }  ;
@5: %empty { cout << "if("; }        ;
@6: %empty { cout << ")" << endl; }  ;
```

In the above, `@3` and `@5` are identical (as are `@4` and `@6`), but bison doesn't check for that; every MRA is considered unique. And that leads to the reduce/reduce conflict, because once the parser has read <kbd>if</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd>, it will need to reduce one of `@3` or `@5` before it can shift the following token, regardless what that token might be, but the next token gives no clue as to whether or not an <kbd>else</kbd> will eventually appear. (Both productions continue with `boolean_statement`, so the following token can be any token in `FIRST(boolean_statement)`, in either case.)

The fact that the conflict is resolved in favour of `@3` (the textually earlier non-terminal) means that `@5` can never be reduced, and bison provides a warning about that. (At least, my version of bison did.)

This is a classic problem with MRAs, sufficiently common that it warrants a section in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Conflicts.html#Mid_002dRule-Conflicts).

In this case, you can fix the problem simply by left-factoring:

```
if_statement:
      if_then
    | if_then ELSE block
    ;

if_then:
      IF '('                   { cout << "if("; }
      boolean_statement ')'    { cout << ")" << endl; }
      block
    ;
```